# View more than last 300 errors in error log?

Tags: linux

cPanel only shows the last 300 errors in the error log, how can I view the entire log, or at least more than that?  This is on a dedicated server with root access, so I assume there is a file somewhere with the entire thing if it can't just be viewed from cPanel.  This is a linux machine.

Edit: I am looking for the error log that shows in cPanel, which is the one that contains PHP errors, etc.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing what type of logs you are looking for (apache/other_web_server/sytem/etc) or your distro the best place to start is in:

`/var/log`

some common logs you may find useful (some may not exists depending on your distro)

- messages
- dmesg
- http/apache* (possibly also located at `<your_apache_prefix>/logs`
- secure
- syslog
- mail or mail.log

Comment: Sorry I didn't think to specify, it is the log that shows the PHP errors, missing file errors, etc.  I may have missed it, but I checked all of the ones you listed there and didn't see it.

Comment: Okay nevermind, it was in /etc/httpd/logs/error_log

Answer (score 3):

In cPanel the last 300 Error log messages are pulled from the file /usr/local/apache/logs/error_log  You can check that file for logs going back longer than 300 lines.

To view that file from the command line you could use:

```
less /usr/local/apache/logs/error_log
```